# copy target folder of custom-maven-plugin to maven projekt with property filtering

Tags: maven, plugins, dependencies, resources

my custom plugin "my-first-plugin" has one `GreetingMojo`:

```java
@Mojo(name = "greeting")
public class GreetingMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    @Parameter(property = "message", defaultValue = "Hello Maven World")
    private String message;
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/tomcat-properties</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-target-folder</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>de.mavenbuch.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>my-first-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                <type>maven-plugin</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/target-from-plugin</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/tomcat-properties</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

at last i have an src/test/resources/plugin_resources_test.property this property:

```
property.one=Message: ${message}
```

all is working if i write:

```
mvn clean install -Dmessage=foo
```

the src/test/resources/plugin_resources_test.property will be overwritten:

```
property.one=Message: foo
```

And here comes my problem:
i have a maven project and i want generate test resources for my tomcat with this plugin.
In my maven project I want to overwrite the properties of the custom plugin and copy them to the target folder. The way I have implemented it now, I can see the file but nothing is overwritten. it always says this:

```
property.one=Message: ${message}
```

Maybe the order in the maven project is not correct or is it not possible to implement something like this at all?

I actually want to implement this plugin in several projects. I would like to save myself having to repeat the same code over and over again.
But it is also important that the plugin has filtering. Then I can control the properties with the parameters.

Basically I would like to have the plugin built from my Maven project and then copy this built target folder with the corresponding file into my Maven project.

Comment: The way I researched it doesn't work. when I call my customPlugin with parameters
"mvn clean install -Dmessage=foo" all variables are replaced in the customPlugin. it should be so.
But when I integrate the customPlugin into my Maven project and include the parameters in the configuration
<message>foo</messaga> then nothing happens.
You can't somehow call the custom plugin from a Maven project and expect the variables to be replaced and returned.
The maven-remote-resources-plugin cannot be used for this either. because that would just copy the resources but without replacing the property.